# Why is specified Time Zone using string parameter in moment.js not being recognized?

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I am attempting to create three moment.js objects, one for the current user's system time, two for a locations opening and closing time on that same day.

First I created a date object as follows:

```
var today = moment();
```

Then I loop through an array of objects:

```
        $(locations).each(function(){ 

                switch(this.time_zone) {
                case 'EST':
                zoneOffset = '-04:00';
                break;
                case 'CST':
                zoneOffset = '-05:00';
                break;
                case 'MST':
                zoneOffset = '-06:00';
                break;
                case 'PST':
                zoneOffset = '-07:00';
                break;
                default:
                zoneOffset = '-04:00';
                }

        var timeOpen = today.format("YYYY")+'-'+today.format("MM")+'-'+today.format("DD")+'T'+this.hours['d'+today.day()+'s']+zoneOffset;
        var timeClose = today.format("YYYY")+'-'+today.format("MM")+'-'+today.format("DD")+'T'+this.hours['d'+today.day()+'e']+zoneOffset;
        openingHrs = moment(timeOpen);
        closingHrs = moment(timeClose);
        console.log(this.id+' '+zoneOffset+' - '+openingHrs.format());
```

I have a switch to check the time_zone of each location. When I console out one of my dates (openingHrs) the result is always an offset of -04 even though the variable zoneOffset indicates otherwise? I assume the default is getting inserted like such:

```
48 -06:00 - 2019-03-21T10:00:00-04:00
49 -05:00 - 2019-03-21T08:30:00-04:00
50 -07:00 - 2019-03-21T11:00:00-04:00
51 -05:00 - 2019-03-21T09:00:00-04:00
52 -05:00 - 2019-03-21T09:00:00-04:00
```

This is what I am working with in the JSON:

```
"time_zone":"CST",
"hours":{
  "d1s":"08:00:00",
  "d1e":"17:00:00",
  "d2s":"08:00:00",
  "d2e":"17:00:00",
  "d3s":"08:00:00",
  "d3e":"17:00:00",
  "d4s":"08:00:00",
  "d4e":"17:00:00",
  "d5s":"08:00:00",
  "d5e":"17:00:00",
  "d6s":"00:00:00",
  "d6e":"00:00:00",
  "d7s":"00:00:00",
  "d7e":"00:00:00"
}
```

I have over 200 "locations" each with varying hours and time zones. Ultimately what I am after is creating a map such that regardless of whether one is in NY, or LA, or somewhere in between, if they look at a marker on the map, I want it to show Open or Closed based upon that locations time zone, etc.

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `this.time_zone` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Thank you. That was my first thought, that it zoneOffset was either not getting a value assigned, OR the switch default value of -04:00 was getting assigned. I changed the switch default to -10:00 and also included value for zoneOffset in the console and it is getting assigned. I just can't figure out why it is not being entered with the string. When I console the timeOpen my string includes the value for zoneOffset. Very strange.

Comment: I even entered a manual value for zoneOffset and it disregards it:


var timeOpen = today.format("YYYY")+'-'+today.format("MM")+'-'+today.format("DD")+'T'+this.hours['d'+today.day()+'s']+'-10:00';
   

openingHrs = moment(timeOpen);
    

console.log(this.id+' '+zoneOffset+' - '+openingHrs.format());

Comment: It may very well be that time zone can not be specified when creating a moment.js object

Comment: No, that is definitely not the case. You'd probably be better off adjusting the local time instance you initially create by a numeric offset from the hour (and maybe minute).

Comment: Thanks again. To do that I'd need to know the time zone of the user yes? Would I grab the offset of the local time instance, use a switch to determine for each location what to add or subtract?

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need to iterate at all? You know the timezone for the locations (because you know the locations) and you can get the timezone for the user's locale so... For that matter, why are you even doing any manual offsetting, with three instances? Your solution isn't even guaranteed to be correct because of different countries changing DST at different times of the year, if at all. Just create a moment.js instance based on the user's locale time, and then make moment.js do the date maths by telling it which timezones the dates you're working with are. It does the rest.

Comment: when you `moment(date)`, it returns in client's timezone

Comment: The basic JavaScript `getTimezoneOffset()` tells you that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/):

> - **moment(...)** is local mode. Ambiguous input (without offset) is    assumed to be local time. Unambiguous input (with offset) is adjusted
>     to local time.
> - **moment.utc(...)** is utc mode. Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC.    Unambiguous input is adjusted to UTC.
> - **moment.parseZone()** keep the input zone passed in. If the input is    ambiguous, it is the same as local mode.
> - **moment.tz(...)** with the moment-timezone plugin can parse input in a    specific time zone.

```js
// when you moment(anything) it is converted to local mode... -03:00 here in São Paulo/BR
console.log(moment('2019-03-21T18:13:38-05:00').format());
console.log(moment().format());
console.log(moment(new Date()).format());

// it you want to keep timezone from input then you should use moment.parseZone()
console.log(moment.parseZone('2019-03-21T18:13:38-05:00').format());
console.log(moment.parseZone(moment().tz('America/Sao_Paulo')).format());
console.log(moment.parseZone('2019-03-21T18:13:38-11:00').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Applying it to your problem, you should:

```
openingHrs = moment.parseZone(timeOpen);
closingHrs = moment.parzeZone(timeClose);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe I solved it as well by doing moment.utc(timeOpen)

Comment: @TMHDesign when using `moment.utc()` it will convert your date and time to utc. for example, if your string is in +05:00 timezone, then `.utc()` will add 5 hours before moving it to utc. If you want to keep all strings having same date and time, changing only timezone, then `.parseZone()` is the way to go.

Comment: Awesome...basically I know the opening and closing time of locations in various time zones, and the time of the current visitor. If I convert all to UTC with respective offsets, then use the inBetween() on the three with user's time between open and close it works. No?

Comment: @TMHDesign if all three are in same zone, it does work

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- If your source file only contains those exact abbreviations (`EST`, `CST`, `MST`, `PST`) then you have a problem already because you're not accounting for daylight saving time for the areas that have it, and you're not accounting for Arizona (most of which is in MST *without* daylight saving time), and you've forgotten about Alaska and Hawaii, and any US territories.  You should examine your data much more closely.
- If you are in control of this source data, then you should avoid using time zone abbreviations at all.  Instead, use [an IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  For the US, the primary identifiers of interest are as follows:

  - `America/New_York` - Eastern Time (EST / EDT)
  - `America/Chicago` - Central Time (CST / CDT)
  - `America/Denver` - Mountain Time (MST / MDT)
  - `America/Phoenix` - Mountain Time (MST only)
  - `America/Los_Angeles` - Pacific Time (PST / PDT)
  - `America/Anchorage` - Alaskan Time (AKST / AKDT)
  - `America/Adak` - Hawaii-Aleutian Time (HAST / HADT)
  - `Pacific/Honolulu` - Hawaii-Aleutian Time (HAST only)

  (This list doesn't include US Territories like Guam, Puerto Rico, American Samoa, etc., but they are on the larger list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).)
- If you are not in control of your data, then instead of mapping the abbreviations to offsets, map them to the identifiers.  (And again, you'll have a problem for Arizona and Aleutian Islands, because you cannot disambiguate on abbreviation alone.)
- If you have data from all over the world, you really shouldn't use time zone abbreviations at all.  There are too many ambiguities, such as `CST` - which could mean US Central Standard Time, Australian Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time.  (There are several others in conflict as well.)
- You can use IANA time zone identifiers with a library such as [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).  You do not need to know the offsets yourself - they are provided through the library.
- It's almost always an anti-pattern to format data to a string just to parse it back to an object again.  Moment makes it so much easier than that.  For example:

  ```
  moment.tz('08:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss', 'America/Chicago').format()
  //=>  "2019-03-22T08:00:00-05:00"
  ```
- In your code, you make an assumption that "today" is the same for the local time zone as it is in the target time zone.  That might not be the case.  Say you ran the code from the other side of the world. They might already be on `2019-03-23` while it's still `2019-03-22` in the US.  If instead you use the code like I showed in the previous bullet point, that is taken care of for you automatically.